# Spring 4 hibernate 4 @Transactional(read-only="true") does not work

Tags: java, spring

I use hibernate 4, spring 4, and I want to use @Transaction annotation, but it doesn't work.

The user object still saved on sqlServer.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

```
[applicationContext.xml]

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:component-scan base-package="SpringDAO"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="SpringTest"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="service"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName"> 
       <value>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</value> 
    </property> 
    <property name="url"> 
        <value>jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=test</value> 
    </property>
    <property name="username"> 
        <value>XXX</value> 
    </property> 
    <property name="password"> 
        <value>XXX</value> 
    </property> 
 </bean>
```

---

```
[hibernate.cfg.xml]

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration> 
    <session-factory> 

        <mapping class="SpringDAO.User" />

    </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

```
package SpringDAO;

@Repository("UserDAO3")
public class UserDAO3 {

SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory value){
    this.sessionFactory = value;
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    return this.sessionFactory;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public boolean insert(Object user){
    Session sess = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    sess.save(user);
    return true;
}
}
```

---

```
package service;

@Service("UserService")
public class UserService {

    public boolean addAction(User user){
        boolean result = true;
        UserDAO3 dao = (UserDAO3)SpringUtil.getBean("UserDAO3");
        List<User> users = dao.searchAllUser();

        for(User selectedUser : users){
            if(selectedUser.getName().equals(user.getName())){
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        result = dao.insert(user);
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Read only is only a hint it doesn't mean it actually does something. However the main issue here is is that you are reading with a different session then saving. The session is readonly but will only apply to entities read into that session. Next to that judging from how you are using spring it wouldn't surprise me that there is also something wrong in your setup. You should use a dependency injection instead of some strange singleton construct (I hope it is a singleton) to retrieve bean instances.

Comment: ia m use context:component-scan in applicationContext.xml, and how to dependency injection?

Comment: Use `@Autowired` to get dependencies you need in a service. Also your transactional boundary should be your service method and not your dao method.

Comment: i already use dependency injection on sessionFactory in UserDAO3 Class, and transactional annotation used in Service Class, but still not work, any idea what I'm doing wrong? tks~

Comment: But you aren't using it everywhere as you should. You are only using it partially. With a bit of luck you are even construct new instances of beans each time you request them leading to very nice to debug issues.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html),

> This just
>   serves as a hint for the actual transaction subsystem; it will not
>   necessarily cause failure of write access attempts. A transaction
>   manager which cannot interpret the read-only hint will not throw an
>   exception when asked for a read-only transaction.

Whether the isolation level of the transaction can change depends on the implementation. Depending on the driver different things might occur, no guarantees, it does not enforce the failure.

Comment: if i want to thorw exception when access DB by the method, how can i do through @Transactional, thank

Comment: @hau-yuChiang You can't; \@Transactional is just not made for that!

Comment: thank your advice, but it resolve by eliminating @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) on primaryKey in the User POJO

Answer (score 0):

POJO:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

Modification:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

---

It works after eliminating `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [@Transactional read-only flag pitfalls](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ts1/#N10149) on ibm.com, the explanation there is really great. Your question is answered there.